# How do I run an Azure WebJobs locally with network failure resilient?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a small website depends on Azure WebJobs for some background tasks.
Due to my basic plan, WebJobs just stops working within 1-2 hours after deployment to Azure, because I need to upgrade my plan.

Meanwhile I run the task on my local machine, and it works fine unless there is a wireless/network failure, apparently it is not network failure resilient. So it does not keep running when network is backup.

I have following basic setup:

```
 hostBuilder.ConfigureWebJobs(webJobsBuilder =>
            {
                webJobsBuilder
                    .AddTimers()
                    .AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
                    .AddAzureStorage()
                    .AddServiceBus();

            });
```

What I am thinking to run another console app to monitor running WebJobs executable and re-run process if it does not exists. But before I do that, I want to learn if there is anything else I can configure in the WebJobs app? I am considering Windows Task scheduler as well, but I don't want to over complicate things.

Comment: I deployed webjob with basic plan and type continues, it is working fine even after 2hrs. Do you have “ALWAYS ON” setting enabled? You can check here: app service -> configuration -> general settings.

Comment: Also sometimes the status is shown as stopped even when it is running backend, you can check log to confirm? this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/853ee57b-8a29-45b5-8190-4978a4c0ad2e/running-webjobs-appear-stopped-in-portal?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) might help for more information. And the basic plans are not network resilient, refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/checklist/resiliency-per-service#azure-load-balancer